# Menu bar is a mess in eclipse neon.3 on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I just installed eclipse neon.3 on Ubuntu 16.10 but the menu bar is a mess in the Java Perspective:

[image]

As you can see from above the menu buttons seems to have been thrown randomly in there and I cannot reorder/drag/move them.

Also save buttons looks like at file is dirty - read to be saved but nothing is changed.

Is Eclipse neon.3 broken on Linux/Ubuntu 16.10?

Resetting the perspective has no effect.

Restarting eclipse and now I have even less buttons in the menu bar:

[image]

Works fine on windows 7.

As suggested below I have tried to add the following to the eclipse.ini:

[image]

But then I can no longer start eclipse and instead get this error:

[image]

Get the impression that eclipse has not been that throughly tested for Linux/Ubuntu.

Comment: Is it possible to move them into position manually?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the perspective? Window > Perspective > Reset

Comment: See original post, it has no effect, just re-opens/re-sizes default editors, does not have any effect on the menu bar. And as I wrote in original post I cannot move them into position manually.

Comment: Its is the same for me. I am running Ubuntu 16.10, too. May you should open a bug!

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 and oxygen (with open JDK 8 from the ubuntu repos). It happens too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having same problem.  I found a solution as follows:

```
export SWT_GTK3=0
eclipse/eclipse
```

I have verified that the above solution works with Ubuntu 16.10, Eclipse neon.2 and JDK 8.

These two bug reports provided the solution:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1634872
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=497705

Comment: On Ubuntu, add this to eclipse.desktop in the following way:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/144968/set-variable-in-desktop-file

Answer (score 1):

Another option to disable GTK 3 is to add the following option to eclipse.ini file:

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

Comment: I tried the above but then I can no longer start eclipse. See updated post

Comment: It should go before the launcher vmargs.  
--launcher.GTK_version
2

Answer (score 0):

I've been through the same problem using the neon.3 and the Ubuntu 17.04.To solve it, I changed my **eclipse.desktop** launcher file (in *~/local/share/applications/*) to set the environment variable *SWT_GTK3*  to 0 as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42195134/1413620) and as showed above:

```
Exec=sh -c "export SWT_GTK3=0 && {path_to_eclipse_folder}/eclipse"
```

but I got some errors while opening and/or editing some files. So reading about a problem while trying to read a markup file I ran into this [forum post](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/235996/). In this post is said that there is a lib needed to be installed to avoid those errors. So after install the lib (as above) everything is working properly.

```
 sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the .ini modification workaround; it needs to be before the vmargs. Like this -

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.550.v20170928-1359
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.dsl.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.GTK_version
2
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx2024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```